# Does cloning the OkHttp client impact connection reuse?

Tags: java, httpclient, okhttp

On the [OkHttp recipes](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes) under "Timeouts / Per call configuration" it says that a timeout can be set per call by cloning the client and then setting the timeout on that cloned object.  Will doing this impact performance?

I'm concerned that cloning the client will interfere with its reuse of existing connections.  Calls to the same server for different resources will have varying timeouts.  I'm using OkHttp server side and want to maximize performance.

Comment: Well they say you can do it so it must work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning won't harm performance. The clone is shallow so you keep the same connection pool, cache, and other dependencies.